# Getting the opposite angle of a circle

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to code in something that gets a random angle from 0 to 359 and then gets the opposite angle from that random angle.

```
double? AngleNoCur = randomAngle ? Random.Next(0, 359) : angle * Math.PI / 180; //'angle' is used for something else, ignore it
double? fixedAngleOpposite = AngleNoCur <= 179 ? AngleNoCur + 180 * Math.PI / 180 : AngleNoCur - 180 * Math.PI / 180;
```

After that I have the part where you add the x, y with (cos) and (sin). I'm sure that's not the problem because I can just put a random angle and it will go to that random angle.

Also negative angles do not work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the opposite angle just `360-angle`?

Comment: @DavidG Nope, I don't think so. Just imagine an angle of 1°

Comment: @MetaColon Yes, that would be 359 then

Comment: @DavidG So... it wouldn't be the opposite, would it?

Comment: @MetaColon What is your definition of opposite then?

Comment: @DavidG Exactly the other site of the circle, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142019/discussion-between-metacolon-and-davidg).

Comment: I'm thinking he is intending like airport runways, where the opposite of runway 1 is 19 ( 180* opposite). So if Angle1 = 15* then its opposite would be 195*

Answer (score 1):

I think you're being confused with radiants. The equation `AngleNoCur + 180 * Math.PI / 180` isn't making much sense for me - you're adding 180 divided by 180 and multiplied by Pi... I think you want you're result in degrees, so just leave that part - 180 is already in degrees. Then it would look like that:

```
double? fixedAngleOpposite = AngleNoCur <= 179 ? AngleNoCur + 180 : AngleNoCur - 180;
```

Furthermore I wouldn't substract 180 degrees under special circumstances - I'd use Modulo:

```
double? fixedAngleOpposite = (AngleNoCur + 180) % 360;
```

However, if you want to get radiants in the end you can use this:

```
fixedAngleOpposite *= Math.PI / 180;
```

Actually I *think* you constantly wanted to work with radiants, because you converted the *angle* - whatever it is, we should ignore it - to radiants. Then your part with the `fixedAngleOpposite` should work, but you should alter the AngleNoCur:

```
double? AngleNoCur = randomAngle ? Random.Next(0, 359) * Math.PI / 180 : angle * Math.PI / 180;
```

However, I'd still suggest using Modulo for `fixedAngleOpposite` and you can shorten your equation:

```
double? fixedAngleOpposite = (AngleNoCur + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI);
```

For more information about degrees and radiants I'd suggest to read through this: http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_net_angles.php.
For more information about Modulo, take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need that  X = host.X + (float)(range * Math.Cos(fixedAngleOpposite.Value)),
                            Y = host.Y + (float)(range * Math.Sin(fixedAngleOpposite.Value)),

Comment: I will try it though.

Comment: Well, there you're using radiants, so you should convert back to radiants. I'll update my post to get radiants again.